# dependency ‘paprbag’ is not available for package ‘data4paprbag’

Tags: r

I tried to download and install the package data4paprbag but unfortunately I got many times more or less the same error:

```
> devtools::install_github("crarlus/data4paprbag")
Downloading GitHub repo crarlus/data4paprbag@master
Skipping 1 packages not available: paprbag
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/Rtmpgk9IIl/remotes7085e1b5add/crarlus-data4paprbag-ad898e8/DESCRIPTION’ (394ms)
─  preparing ‘data4paprbag’:
 ✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
─  building ‘data4paprbag_0.1.1.tar.gz’ (23.2s)

Installing package into ‘/home/ibraim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency ‘paprbag’ is not available for package ‘data4paprbag’
* removing ‘/home/ibraim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/data4paprbag’
Error in i.p(...) : 
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmpgk9IIl/file7084352805e/data4paprbag_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(remote_deps$package) :
is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Do you have any suggestion how to proceed ?
Many thanks.

Comment: So have you tried installing the package that the error tells you is a dependency?

Comment: Try running `devtools::install_github("crarlus/paprbag")` first.